# Bootstrap adjusting columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a currency conversion tool. My problem is that the rows collapses too soon when I reduce the width of the window. I would like them to always stay in proportion.

https://jsfiddle.net/a4bz0x4m/

How do I fix this problem?

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">

        <a id="selectCurrency-button" class="ui-selectmenu ui-selectmenu-dropdown">
        <span class="ui-selectmenu-status">
            <span>
                <div class="flag usd"></div>
                <span class="ui-selectmenu-item-content">
                    <span class="currency-name">United States Dollars</span>
                    <span class="currency-code">$ USD</span>
                </span>
            </span>
        </span>
            <span class="ui-selectmenu-icon"></span>
        </a>

    </div>


</div>

<div class="row">

    <div class="col-sm-5">
        <label>Australian Dollars</label>
        <div class="input-wrapper">
            <input id="inputCurrencyFrom" type="text" maxlength="8">
            <div class="flag aud"></div>
            <span class="currency-code ng-binding">AUD</span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-2 equal-sign">=</div>

    <div class="col-sm-5">

        <label>United States Dollars</label>
        <div class="input-wrapper">
            <input id="inputCurrencyTo" type="text" maxlength="8">
            <div class="flag usd"></div>
            <span class="currency-code ng-binding">USD</span>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Here is an example of what I am trying to achieve:http://www.nab.com.au/personal/international/travel/foreign-exchange-rates

Comment: Add `col-xs-*` for smaller devices. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a4bz0x4m/1/)

Comment: I've tried that but at a certain point it stops shrinking and the right side of the select bar gets hidden by the browser.

Comment: You have fixed the width of calculator to 600px and hence the scrollbar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the col-xs-* classes for smaller devices. You can set the calculators width to 600px only for sm and lg classes usign media query

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
.calculator { width: 600px; margin: 0 auto;}
}
```

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a4bz0x4m/5/)

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `col-xs-*` class on the element. like:

```
<div class="col-xs-5">
        <label>Australian Dollars</label>
        <div class="input-wrapper">
            <input id="inputCurrencyFrom" type="text" maxlength="8">
            <div class="flag aud"></div>
            <span class="currency-code ng-binding">AUD</span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-2 equal-sign">=</div>

    <div class="col-xs-5">

        <label>United States Dollars</label>
        <div class="input-wrapper">
            <input id="inputCurrencyTo" type="text" maxlength="8">
            <div class="flag usd"></div>
            <span class="currency-code ng-binding">USD</span>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: Tried it. doesn't fix the problem, just gives it more range.